# Refactoring javascript functions for reuse

Tags: javascript, refactoring, this

I have this lovely, well written function (thanks to [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css-custom-properties-theming/) (good article btw) - see [Codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/ybgNKP?editors=1010)):

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--mainColor",
localStorage.getItem("userThemeColor"));
var colorInput = document.querySelector("#choose-theme-color");


colorInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--mainColor", this.value);
localStorage.setItem("userThemeColor", this.value);

});
```

I use it more than once, so to avoid duplication I want to refactor it into a reusable function. I've been at it all day and am having real trouble getting the querySelector value (this.value and anything else I've named it) into the reworked function. Everything I've tried breaks the function (thought I'd broken Codepen a coupla times too...) or ends up with 'value not defined'

If I can see how it's done, I'm sure it'll make more sense to me and I'll be able to apply the same logic elsewhere in my code. I'm trying to learn 'good practice', so if anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks in advance.

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--mainColor", localStorage.getItem("userThemeColor"));
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--footerColor", localStorage.getItem("userFooterColor"));

var colorInput1 = document.querySelector("#choose-theme-color");
var colorInput2 = document.querySelector("#choose-theme-2");

var color1 = new Picker("--mainColor", "userThemeColor");
var color2 = new Picker("--footerColor", "userFooterColor");

// Object contructor
function Picker(arg1, arg2){

//  this.arg1 = arg1; // property to set - not req'd
//  this.arg2 = arg2; // local property item - not req'd

  this.setStyles = function() { // this.value is original code
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(arg1, this.value);
  localStorage.setItem(arg2, this.value);
  }
}

colorInput1.addEventListener("change", color1.setStyles);
colorInput2.addEventListener("change", color2.setStyles);

// 14 LINES OF CODE / AGAINST 6 X 2 IF USING DUPLICATES OF THE ORIGINAL
```

Comment: How have you tried to refactor it? Show us one of your attempts and the errors that came with it.

Comment: It's not clear to me which parts you want to be reusable. In general, to factor things out into a function, move everything into the function and replace the things that are variable with parameters.

Comment: @MikeC - yes, I've been watching videos on the basics, checking threads and trying who knows what all day.

Comment: @Felix - I just want more than 1 colour picker and thought it would be more efficient (and good practice) to make the function reusable. I think I got close, but no joy. Until now... OMG! Just got it working, sort of...(will post above).  I took an object constructor I wrote before and reworked it for this. It works, but I don't think it's the best way to do it, as it ends up much longer than the original. What am I missing? How do I refactor the original code, so it can be reused?